# How to store JWT tokens in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jwt

Which is the best and reliable library to store token and other data like id that maybe required later when the users are interacting with the application?

Comment: you can also try react-native-mmkv-storage https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mmkv-storage?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 2):

You can store data in your application when using `React Native` with:

- [SecureStore](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) from `Expo` for saving critical data, like a `JWT`.
- [React Native Async Storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) for non  critical data.